# elasticsearch inner join

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with some fields, my documents contains valid "category" data also contains "url"(analyzed field) data but not contains respsize..
in the other hand documents that contains "respsize" data (greater than 0) also contains "url" data but not contains "category" data..
I think you got the point, I need join or intersection whatever that a query returns all documents contains respsize and category that have same same url documents.

Here what I did so far;(url field analyzed, rest of them not_analyzed)

here documents that have category:
[image]

and other documents have respsize that I need to combine them based on url
[image]

I need a dsl query that return records that have same url token(in this scenario it will be www.domainname.com) with merge category and respsize,
I simply want field in second img "category":"27" like in img1 but of course with rest of all fields.

here is my query but not work

```
GET webproxylog/accesslog/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter" : {
            "and" : {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "not": {
                          "filter": {
                            "terms": {
                              "category": [
                                "-",
                                "-1",
                                "0"
                              ]
                            },
                            "term": {
                              "respsize": "0"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "term": {
                          "category": "www.hurriyet.com.tr"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "_cache" : true
            }
        }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "respsize": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the query below. It will require the `url` field to be the one you specify (i.e. `must`) and then either of the next two clauses (i.e. `should`) must be true, i.e. `category` should be not one of the given terms or the `respsize` must be greater than 0.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "url": "www.hurriyet.com.tr"
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "not": {
                "terms": {
                  "category": [
                    "-",
                    "-1",
                    "0"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "respsize": {
                  "gt": 0
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Valentin, thanks for this answer, my real issue about problem in this post, can you check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931757/how-to-update-multiple-documents-that-match-a-query-in-elasticsearch

Comment: hi Val, can you check this post; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015533/elasticsearch-having-not-query Thank you.