# How to update multiple documents that match a query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents which contains only "url"(analyzed) and "respsize"(not_analyzed) fields at first. I want to update documents that match the url and add new field "category"
I mean;
at first doc1:

```
{
 "url":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/4005632/mehmet-yener-yilmaz",
 "respsize":"500"
}
```

I have an external data and I know "stackoverflow.com" belongs to category 10,
And I need to update the doc, and make it like:

```
{
 "url":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/4005632/mehmet-yener-yilmaz",
 "respsize":"500",
 "category":"10"
}
```

Of course I will do this all documents which url fields has "stackoverflow.com"
and I need the update each doc oly once.. Because category data of url is not changeable, no need to update again.
I need to use _update api with _version number to check it but cant compose the dsl query.
**EDIT**
I run this and looks works fine:
[image]
But documents not changed..
[image]

Although query result looks true, new field not added to docs, need refresh or etc?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You could use the [update by query plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery) in order to do just that. The idea is to select all document without a `category` and whose `url` matches a certain string and add the category you wish.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/webproxylog/_update_by_query' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "url": "stackoverflow.com"
              }
            },
            {
              "missing": {
                "field": "category"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script" : "ctx._source.category = \"10\";"
}'
```

After running this, all your documents with `url: stackoverflow.com` that don't have a category, will get `category: 10`. You can run the same query again later to fix new `stackoverflow.com` documents that have been indexed in the meantime.

Also make sure to enable scripting in `elasticsearch.yml` and restart ES:

```
script.inline: on 
script.indexed: on
```

In the script, you're free to add as many fields as you want, e.g.

```
  ...
  "script" : "ctx._source.category1 = \"10\"; ctx._source.category2 = \"20\";"
```

**UPDATE**

ES 2.3 now features the [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) functionality. You can still use the above query exactly as is and it will work (except that `filtered` and `missing` are deprecated, but still working ;).

Comment: The first `term` in your update-by-query should be on field `heroname` not `url`. The screenshots don't seem to have anything in common with the initial documents in your question.

Comment: is your `heroname` field analyzed or not? if you add the `missing` filter to your search query at the top, what do you get?

Comment: its analyzed, real field data Wrath King and SAND KING but I can get these docs with term:"king"

Comment: you mean search query like this; "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "heroname": "king"
              }
            },
            {
              "missing": {
                "field": "myfield"
              }
            }
          ]
        }... same result returns this 2 docs

Comment: Yes what happens if you run just the query without the script part, i.e. the idea is to figure out the documents matched that would be updated by the script.

Comment: Oh wait I see the issue... you just need to post on `/dota2/_update_by_query` without the `/agust` part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91350/discussion-between-mehmet-yener-yilmaz-and-val).

Comment: Hello, I wonder if I can add 2 field in same query string: like this;
 POST myindex/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
    ..
  },
  "script" : "ctx._source.category = \"10\"",
  "script" : "ctx._source.category2 = \"20\""
}

Comment: Yes, you can but in the same script. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: This is not yet working in 2.x ES. https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery/issues/46

Comment: ES 2.3 now features the [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) functionality !!

Comment: I have been trying to do this but I keep getting the following error:
`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"class_cast_exception","reason":"java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map"}],"type":"class_cast_exception","reason":"java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map"},"status":500}`
I don't understand why is this error being thrown. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: @KeshavAgarwal I suggest you create a new question for this

Answer (score 1):

That all sounds great but just to add to @Val answer, Update By Query is available form ElasticSearch 2.x but not for earlier versions. In our case we're using 1.4 for legacy reasons and there is no chance of upgrading in forseeable future so another solution is using the Update by query plugin provided here: https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery