# Update by query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run `update by query` on my elasticsearch index using the method provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931757/how-to-update-multiple-documents-that-match-a-query-in-elasticsearch) answer. This is the query that I've been trying to run:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/_update_by_query' -d '
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "latest_uuid":"d56ffe2095f511e6bcdd0acbdf0298e3"
    }
  },
  "script" : "ctx._source.is_in_stock = \"false\";"
}'
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "class_cast_exception",
                "reason": "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map"
            }
        ],
        "type": "class_cast_exception",
        "reason": "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map"
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try "_update_by_query?is_in_stock=false" and delete script line to see if problem is script

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

Turns out that I had to use the following as script:

```
"script":{"inline":"ctx._source.is_in_stock = false"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem can be the \"false\" (String value) who no want to be cast.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/_update_by_query' -d '
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "latest_uuid":"d56ffe2095f511e6bcdd0acbdf0298e3"
    }
  },
  "script" : "ctx._source.is_in_stock = false;"
}'
```

You can first try it. Waiting your feedback ! :)

Comment: Hi, I found the problem and have added an answer corresponding to that. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Yes I see, we post in the same time, GGWP !