# How to add a new field in all the documents indexed in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to add a new field in all the indexed documents in elastic search,

is there any way(for normal & nested documents)

Comment: Is it mandatory to do exactly that? Can't the code handle it when necessary? Like when it access data, use the default value you'd put, and on every save, make sure to add it. You'd have documents with it, and some without it but it would slowly get to the point where you want...

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your remarks, i have around 16,50,453 records , i thought of doing it by scripting (ES), is there any way to do this.? i need to add new field with default value at one go.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931757/how-to-update-multiple-documents-that-match-a-query-in-elasticsearch/32941245#32941245 (hint: use update-by-query)

Comment: Thanks Val... !!!! tried with your posted answer

Comment: But im getting POST /kp/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script" : "ctx._source.category = \"10\";"
}

Comment: "type": "class_cast_exception",
        "reason": "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map"

Comment: did you try this: `"script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.category = \"10\";" 
  }` ?

Comment: Thanks, A lot .!!!! Val, it solved my issue