# ElasticSearch - Copy one field value to other field for all documents

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a field "name" in the index. We recently added a new field "alias".
I want to copy name field value to the new field alias for all documents.

Is there any Update query that will do this? 
If that is not possible , Help me to achieve this.
Thanks in advance

I am trying this query 
http://URL/index/profile/_update_by_query

```
{
  "query": {

        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "exists" : { "field" : "name" }
            }
        }

  },
  "script" : "ctx._source.alias = name;"
}
```

In the script , I am not sure how to give name field.
I getting error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "class_cast_exception",
        "reason": "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map"
      }
    ],
    "type": "class_cast_exception",
    "reason": "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931757/how-to-update-multiple-documents-that-match-a-query-in-elasticsearch/32941245#32941245 (hint: use the update-by-query API)

Comment: @Val Thanks , Updated question, Please check now

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Indeed, the syntax has changed a tiny little bit since. You need to modify your query to this:

```
POST index/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "exists" : { "field" : "name" }
            }
        }

  },
  "script" : {
      "inline": "ctx._source.alias = ctx._source.name;"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE for ES 6**

Use `source` instead of `inline`

Comment: When I am trying this I am getting "scripts of type [inline], operation [update] and lang [groovy] are disabled" .

Comment: You've not read the other question to the end. You need to enable dynamic scripting.

Comment: Yes,  Thanks a lot

Comment: For version > 6, use `source` instead of `inline` inside `script`

Comment: can you please share the full query? if it's GET or PUT and how the index name should be written? thanks