# ElasticSearch: POST update without Index, Type and Id

Tags: elasticsearch, post

Here is one of my documents in elasticsearch:

```
{
            "_index": "2017-10-21",
            "_type": "cat",
            "_id": "14",
            "_score": 2.2335923,
            "_source": {
                "name": "Biscuit",
                "breed": "Persian",
                "age": "3"
            }
}
```

I know that it's possible to do a `POST update` to add a new field to an existing document this way:

```
POST [index] / [type] / [id] / _update
```

So for example, if I want to add a new field "hairy" to my document:

```
POST 2017-10-21 / cat / 14 / _update

{
     "script" : "ctx._source.hairy = 'yes'"
}
```

I will have this result:

```
{
            "_index": "2017-10-21",
            "_type": "cat",
            "_id": "14",
            "_source": {
                "name": "Biscuit",
                "breed": "Persian",
                "age": "3",
                "hairy": "yes"
            }
}
```

However, I would like to add a new field to ALL my documents, no matter their index, type or id. Unfortunately, even after hours of research I haven't found a way to do a `POST update` without using index, type or id.

So, my questions are: Is it even possible? If it's not, is there another way to do what I want to do?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931757/how-to-update-multiple-documents-that-match-a-query-in-elasticsearch/32941245#32941245

Comment: Thank you @Val I have finally found the solution through your link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a solution!

I needed to use `POST update_by_query` instead of `POST update`

```
POST * / _update_by_query
{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.hairy = 'yes'"
    }
}
```

The star means that you want to select all existing indexes/indices