# elasticsearch add field to all documents

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I'm new here.

I have about 200 thousand documents in one index, all have same type. I want to add one more field "category" (which is a keyword string) to every single document.

Is there a convenient way to achieve this? I know normally one query only gets 10000 documents

Thank you very much

Comment: what did you try? where did it fail?

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931757/how-to-update-multiple-documents-that-match-a-query-in-elasticsearch/32941245#32941245 (hint: use update-by-query)

Answer (score 14):

```
POST index_name/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.field_name = \"value\"",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 8):

Late but hope this can help you.

You can use [_update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-api-source) API.

Be aware that you can define **conditions** for your update with the **query** part of the request. If you just need to update all the documents in your index, you can simply delete the **query** part.

```
POST my-index-000001/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.count++",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user.id": "kimchy"
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**: the `inline` option inside `_update_by_query` is depreciated since 6.x. You should use `source` instead.