# get updated doc ids in Elasticsearch's update_by_query api

Tags: elasticsearch

I use the following query to update some weight filed in matched docs. I need to get the list of updated docs id but I don't know how to do that?

```
    POST v1_shingle_analyzer/_update_by_query
{
    "script" : {
        "source": "ctx._source.content_completion.weight ++",
        "lang": "painless",
        "_source":true,
        "_source_includes":"_id"
    
    },
    "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": ["ad22784cde0cecab176811ca9d77e7c2","dssdg784cde0cecab176811ca9fgdfg"]
     
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way. You can query the Id's again to check whether it updated.

Comment: @Gibbs Are you sure? If you are, post it as answer and I will accept it

Comment: Sure. I will do little more research and give you a detailed answer.

Comment: I also don't think there is a way of doing this, I less efficient and I guess the only way of doing is first get version of all the document, and after updation of the index see if version is updated for those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html), [this legend answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931757/how-to-update-multiple-documents-that-match-a-query-in-elasticsearch), [this plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery) and few ES forum posts, JIRAs.

**Short answer:**

There is no direct way of doing this. You may need to query again with the `IDs` to check whether it changed.

**Detailed answer:**

As per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-response-body), Response doesn't have a field to return the updated `IDs`.

The plugin mentioned is deprecated/dropped the support to context as per the `GitHub` link. But I think that

1. you can look at the source code to figure out a way to get the `IDs` updated If it really matters.
2. I see [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2230) that there is a response option. We can set three values. But it doesn't say anything about returning IDs. It says options related to which shard, what type is updated, etc.. You can look at this if there is anyway to tweak this.

Kindly let me know for more information.