# How to check for key(last_password_changed_at) exists in index if not exists, Update the `field' in the accounts index to current date using python

Tags: python, api, elasticsearch

currently I am working on API in python which will check the password validity(Users will require to change their password for every 60 days), need to check whether the key(**last_password_changed_at**)exists in **account** index, If exists I simply take the key and compare with today datetime it will give no. of days and check the condition(<=60, >60)and returns an **should_update** flag with a Boolean value, If not exists updating the `**last_password_changed_at**' in the accounts index to current date & time. This is my code.

```
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
    client = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', }])
    profile = client.search(
        index='accounts',
        doc_type='accounts',
        scroll='5m',
        size=100,
        body={
            "query": {
                 "match": {
                    "username": request_object.username_or_email
                }
            }
        })
    import datetime
    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    for info in profile['hits']['hits']:
        if (info['_source']['last_password_changed_at']):
            format_last_password_changed_at = datetime.datetime.strptime((info['_source']['last_password_changed_at']),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
            days_diff = (current_datetime - format_last_password_changed_at).days
            # if (days_diff == 0) or (days_diff <= 60):
            if (days_diff > 60):
                last_password_changed_at  = format_last_password_changed_at
                return jsonify({"should_update": bool(days_diff), "last_password_update": last_password_changed_at })
            else:
            # elif (days_diff == 0) or (days_diff <= 60):
                last_password_changed_at = format_last_password_changed_at
                return jsonify({"should_update": bool(days_diff), "last_password_update": last_password_changed_at })
        if (info['_source']['last_password_changed_at'] not in info):
            print('if field not exists, creating the field and updating last_password_changed_at to current datetime')
            updating_current_datetime = info.update(
            body={
                "script": {
                    "source": "ctx._source.last_password_changed_at+= last_password_changed_at",
                    "params": {
                        "last_password_changed_at": current_datetime
                    },
                },
                "query": {
                    "match": {
                        "_id": info['_id']
                    }
                }
            }
            )
            # i['_source']['last_password_changed_at'] = current_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            return jsonify({"should_update": 'false', "last_password_update": updating_current_datetime})

**Expected output 1:**(If >60 days)

    {
      "should_update": true,
      "last_password_update": "2021-01-03T08:32:36.054082",
    }
             
         

**Expected output 2:**(If <=60 days)

    {
      "should_update": False,
      "last_password_update": "2021-01-03T08:32:36.054082",
    }
```

Here is my **account** index

```
{
  "settings": {
  },
  "mappings": {
    "accounts": {
      "dynamic": false,
      "properties": {
        "username": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword",
            }
          }
        },
        "password": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "email": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "search": {
              "type": "text",
            }
          }
        },
       
        "last_password_changed_at": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above code is working for user account who's having  **last_password_changed_at**(field) and not working for account don't have this **last_password_changed_at**(field), means only if condition is working all the time.

**Error:**
if (info['_source']['last_password_changed_at']):

KeyError: 'last_password_changed_at'

please help me guys

Comment: Would this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931757/how-to-update-multiple-documents-that-match-a-query-in-elasticsearch ?

Comment: Did you try `if ('last_password_changed_at' in info['_source']  and  info['_source']['last_password_changed_at']):` ?

Comment: On the other hand, you need to set current time for `last_password_changed_at` field. The problem here, it is. No need to check while looping the users. After the password change you need to set again.

Answer (score 0):

```
for info in profile['hits']['hits']:
    item = info['_source']
    item1 = info['_source']['last_password_changed_at']
    last_password_changed_details = item.get('last_password_changed_at')
    if (last_password_changed_details):
            print('I have a field')
    if not last_password_changed_details:
            print('i dont have a field')
```