# elasticsearch "having not" query

Tags: elasticsearch

Some documents has category fields.. Some of these docs has category fields its value equals to "-1". I need a query return documents which have category fields and "not equal to -1".

I tried this:

```
GET webproxylog/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {

      "filter": {
        "not":{
          "filter": {"and": {
            "filters": [
              {"term": {
                "category": "-1"
              }

              },
              {
                "missing": {
                "field": "category"
                }
              }
            ]
          }}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But not work.. returns docs not have "category field"

EDIT

Mapping:

```
    {
   "webproxylog": {
      "mappings": {
         "accesslog": {
            "properties": {
               "category": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "clientip": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "clientmac": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "clientname": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "duration": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "filetype": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "hierarchycode": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "loggingdate": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
               },
               "reqmethod": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "respsize": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "resultcode": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "url": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "slash_analyzer"
               },
               "user": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `category` field is `string` and is analyzed by default, then your `-1` will be indexed as `1` (stripping the `minus` sign).

You will need that field to be `not_analyzed` or to add a sub-field which is not analyzed (as my solution below).

Something like this:

```
DELETE test

PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "category": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "notAnalyzed": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /test/test/1
{"category": "-1"}
POST /test/test/2
{"category": "2"}
POST /test/test/3
{"category": "3"}
POST /test/test/4
{"category": "4"}
POST /test/test/5
{"category2": "-1"}

GET /test/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "category.notAnalyzed": {
              "value": "-1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "filtered": {
            "filter": {
              "missing": {
                "field": "category"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed mapped to not_ananlyzed (edited question). but query still returns documents have no category field

Comment: Have you re-indexed the documents after the mapping change?

Comment: And have you tested with my query or yours?

Comment: yes re-index all, I triedt  both of our queries. but not work.. your query returns nothing mine returns doc have no category field

Comment: I think yours is true let me one min

Comment: Note that if you didn't add the subfield, but just changed the mapping the query should be `GET /test/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "category": {
              "value": "-1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "filtered": {
            "filter": {
              "missing": {
                "field": "category"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`